# How can I search a specific type of file on a macOS with a condition?

Tags: macos, filesystem, spotlight

I want to search only files created by Fl Studio but if I search in Spotlight for files with the .flp extension I get also the autosaved versions of the files.

Is there any way to search only the .flp files and not the autosaved versions?

Comment: Do the autosaved versions have the same ".flp" extension? If so, that makes it tough. There are certainly ways to make subtle distinctions by using command line programs, but you have to understand what the differences are between the originals and the backups.

Comment: Open finder to the top-level directory you wish to search
Press ⌘ + F
- From the search menu options, on the left, choose “other”
- Click the checkbox under the In Menu column for file extension from the popup window and close the popup window by pressing “OK”
- Select file extension from the search menu
- Type your file extension in the text field

Answer (score 0):

Rather than make us guess what’s on your filesystem, can you open a command line and drag one instance of each file to determine what’s searchable?

The `mdls` command lists all filesystem metadata (which is what you search) and the `file` command looks at the contents. Type the word `mdls` and then drag in one file you want to find and a second file you want to exclude. Repeat for `file` and post the output. We will see the file name and metadata, so remember that before posting public data.